# What I can do in LUKS when I'm asked for password?

Tags: linux, encryption, luks, disk-encryption

When I start PC it asks for my password to boot in system. 1) But I cannot use CAPSLOCK when I use CAPSLOCK the light on my keyboard is not lighting. 
2) Does SHIFT button work ?
3) Can I delete a character if it's typed wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to enter uppercase characters.

To delete a character, just use the <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> key, then enter the correct character.